# How to remove the probable dot at the beginning/end of string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

I tried this:

```
echo preg_replace('/[^,,$]/', '', ',test,hi,');
```

But gets:

```
,,,
```

Comment: It is a comma, not a dot... :o)

Comment: Got to love that comment ^ XD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean

```
preg_replace('/^,|,$/', '', ',test,hi,');
```

? Inside a character class `[…]`, a leading `^` means negation, and `$` doesn't have any special meanings.

You could use the [`trim` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) instead.

```
trim(',test,hi,', ',');
```

Comment: @wamp: Because this is a character group and it says *replace everything that is not a comma or a dollar sign* (a `^` at the beginning of such a group negates the group).

Comment: @wamp: Because `[^,,$]` means "any characters except `,`, `,` and `$`".

Answer (score 4):

preg_replace is a bit overkill

```
$string = ',,ABCD,EFG,,,,';
$newString trim($string,',');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
trim(',test,hi,',','); // echoes test,hi
```